# How to right deploy and work in a MERN project?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, deployment, mern

This is the first time I will deploy a project on the MERN stack. I have a number of questions, I will be grateful for your help:

- I will deploy to Heroku, where is mongodb transferred to if I have it on the local server? Will I have 2 bases, one for development, the other for production?
- In the future, how can I roll out updates, for example, did I do something on the local server, then git push, and then how to accept the changes on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

*First of all, be sure that you have read the documentation of Heroku.*

- You cant install MongoDB on the Heroku dyno. You have to use any MongoDB addon or you can connect ani remote running MongoDB instance to your app.
  For example - Make an instance on MongoDB instance and connect it to your app using the connection string.
- You can roll out updates using git push from your project repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the code directly to the Heroku using the command:

`$ git push heroku master`

For this, you need to setup remote origin to the Heroku. Do check the Heroku documentation for this. After you push the code using the above command to the Heroku then Heroku will automatically publish the changes based on the configuration you had provided.
For hosting the MongoDB database, check the MongoDB documentation. You can create a remote MongoDB database in the MongoDB cloud. After that, you can use it anywhere in your application.